# mysql - wins ranking no tie

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I have a problem in the ranking of each user is perfect, the problem is when the user "a" has the same result as the user "b"

My code

```
  SELECT ID, Wins, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM users WHERE Wins>x.Wins) AS rank_upper, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Wins>=x.Wins) AS rank_lower 
 FROM `users` x WHERE x.username='$_GET[user]'

ID   wins Rank
 1    23    1
 2    17    2
 3    17    2
 4    10    3
 5    10    3
```

I like it like this:

```
 ID   wins Rank
 1    23    1
 2    17    2
 3    17    3
 4    10    4
 5    10    5
```

Comment: What makes you say that `ID 2` is `Rank 2` while `ID 3` is `Rank 3` when their win count is the same?

Comment: is just one example, I want the result of the user who has the same point is different ranking

Comment: sql injection see [link](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/preventing-and-fixing-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-in-php-applications/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing also id might work for you

```
SELECT ID, Wins, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM users WHERE Wins>x.Wins or (Wins=x.Wins and id<x.id)) AS Rank 
 FROM `users` x WHERE x.username='$_GET[user]'
```

Comment: it does not work. I make the call with this code to the result <?php 
    
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

   printf($row["Rank"]);
   
}    
   
 
?>

Comment: @DanielHernandez - do NOT use `mysql_fetch_arry()` -- the whole `mysql_xxx()` API in PHP is obsolete. Use `mysqli_xxx()` or PDO library instead. Also, NEVER NEVER put `$_GET` variables directly into your query string. At the least, you must use proper escaping techniques, but better to use prepared statements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/ for more info

Comment: @simba hi, Could you give me an example of how it should be please

Comment: @DanielHernandez easiest way would be to point you toward a good quality tutorial -- see http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases